# iOS app - users updating wait time

Tags: iphone, xml, interaction

I am building an iPhone app in which users (or employees) will be able to go to restaurants and update/give an estimate of the waiting time at that location. To do something like this, would it be most efficient to use an XML webpage and parse the data that is currently there and update that value with the user's input then reload the XML database? Obviously any user should be able to update the site so it needs to be done from a web-server.

Also, if anyone knows of a similar example for this, that would be spectacular!

Thanks for your help,

Comment: your app idea is not been understood. Can you eloberate?

Comment: So if a user goes into a restaurant (or other place of business which people must wait) they can get on the app and estimate the amount of time someone would have to wait to be served. Thus, the user would update the estimated wait time for that location and all other app users would be able to see other users' updates. I am asking, is it most logical to use an XML page on a webserver to update this estimated time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a textfield in which you can fill the value and then send it onto the web server through XML or JSON web service and the other users can see the update from the web service.

Comment: I am just having trouble figuring out how to update the xml file and put it back on the webserver with a new value.